# I can't seem to find how to hide the pdf tool bar in jsPDF.JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, pdf, jspdf

How do i hide pdf toolbar with iframe and jsPDF so that the user can't print or download the pdf i just want them to see the preview of the document.

index.php

```
<section class="inner-page">
        <div class="container">
            <p>
                <iframe title="description" id="exam" width="1000" height="1000"></iframe>
                <input type="text" id="testinputpdf" value="this is a test value">
            </p>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Script

```
<script>
    const {
        jsPDF
    } = window.jspdf;

    const doc = new jsPDF();
    doc.text("Hello world!", 10, 10);
    doc.viewerPreferences({
        "HideToolbar": true,
        "HideMenubar": true,
        "HideWindowUI": true,
        "NumCopies": 10
    }, true);

    $("#exam").attr('src', doc.output('datauristring'));

</script>
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqL5w.png)

Comment: The PDF toolbar is displayed by the browser. There's nothing you can do to control it from client-side JS. Also note that if you're displaying the file as a PDF in the browser, then it's already been downloaded to the client PC and the user is free to open/print/screenshot it as they see fit. So the point here really is, if you don't want the PDF file to be publicly available, don't show it to the user.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan oh okay thanks! i'll probably just start from copying the design of pdf content so i will able to add preview of the document in the client-side